# How to integrate rules in the openL rule service with java code

Tags: java, rule-engine

I have an interface class like this

```
    public interface Simple {
    Double AirTicketPrice(String departureCity, String destinationCity);
}
```

I have a method as follows

```
void openlTest() {
    RulesEngineFactory<Simple> engineFactory = new RulesEngineFactory<> 
    ("C:/dump/TicketsPrice.xlsx");
    engineFactory.setInterfaceClass(Simple.class);
    Simple rules = (Simple) engineFactory.newInstance();
    rules.AirTicketPrice("Chicago", "Madrid");

}
```

and I have TicketsPrice.xlsx file in which the rules are defined i.e on entering the departure and destination city, the ticket amount will be returned.

So can anyone explain how to read/test those rules in openL tablet rule service from the java code. I've the above mentioned method but it is not working.